# Control order of vertically stacked elements using only CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use the [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) to control the order that elements are rendered. Here's some sample HTML (and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/dnew63of/6/)):

```
<div id='outer-container'>

    <div id='blue-objects' class='object-container'>
        <p>In here we have a number of blue things.</p>
        <p>The amount of content could be very small, or very large.</p>
    </div>

    <div id='green-objects' class='object-container'>
        <p>This is very similar to the blue objects block, in that the amount of content is unknown at design-time, and it could be very small or very large.</p>
        <p>It could be a complicated, nested set of child objects, although in this example there is nothing more than two &lt;p&gt; elements.</p>
    </div>
</div>

/* Started with a columnar layout as given by the Flexplorer: http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/ */
.outer-container {    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;

}

.object-container {
    -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
    flex: 1 auto;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#blue-objects {
    order: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#green-objects {
    order: 1;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

My goal is to be able to use pure CSS to control the order the #blue-objects and #green-objects elements appear. All I've been able to accomplish so far is control the horizontal sort order.

The spec describes the `order` property [as follows](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-order):

> A flex container lays out its content in order-modified document
>   order, starting from the lowest numbered ordinal group and going up.

I would have thought this would mean that the #green-objects would appear before #blue-objects, because of the `order` values being 1 and 2, respectively... but it's [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/dnew63of/6/) in Chrome 36, Firefox 31, or IE 11.

According to caniuse.com, flexbox has good support in modern browsers. **What am I doing wrong**? How can I control the order of a vertically stacked set of elements using the CSS Flexible Box Layout module? Help with this fiddle would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, if there's another way to control the display order besides CSS Flexbox, I'm all ears. But I'm thinking this is the only way to do it in CSS, besides using absolute positioning (which won't work in my case because I don't know the dimensions of the elements at design time).

Comment: You have an element with the `id` "outercontainer" but nothing with the *`class`* "outercontainer".  [Here's an updated version of your gist with the class changed to an ID in your CSS and it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/dnew63of/7/)

Comment: Wow, that is too embarrassing for words :-(

Comment: I think this question should be deleted but when I click "delete" it warns me that deleting a question with an answer can result in a ban.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `#outer-container` and not `.outer-container` in CSS file. Then the flex model will be triggered.

To only put blue objects last, then just apply: **`order:1;`** to it and nothing to others:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dnew63of/8/)**

*Order defaut value is 0.*